# Efficient Amazon style 'customer also viewed' SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I figured out that I need only record a client session id and a viewed product id in order to acheive this. Here is my table script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[pagevisits](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [xsession] [int] NULL,
    [xpagename] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I've come up with a query that seems to work OK

```
select top 5 xpagename, COUNT(xpagename)as total 
FROM pagevisits 
WHERE pagevisits.xsession in (SELECT pagevisits.xsession 
                              FROM pagevisits \
                              WHERE pagevisits.xpagename = 20 
                              AND pagevisits.xsession != 539447381 ) 
AND pagevisits.xpagename != 20 
GROUP BY xpagename 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

However being a bit of a novice at SQL I'm fearful that as this table is likely to grow quite large, will this choke the server? Is there a better way to do it or am I OK?

Comment: If you are concerned about size, you can help reduce it by applying some constraints to your requirements. For instance, do you only care about "viewed" when the user went directly from that page to another? That won't reduce the record count, but will make the query easier. Alternatively, do you only care about views in the last x days/weeks/months/years? If yes, then you can periodically trim the table of irrelevant information (or partition it if you want the data just in case)

Comment: Amazon use "People who bought this also bought", likely because they have to have that information anyway, and it's not going to be as extensive as "People who viewed also viewed".

Comment: Yes that is correct. The extra select allows my to find what other people have seen so I can count the most viewed items and find the five most popular.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you need an inner SELECT there. If you want to select the pages visited by the customer in the existing session (assumption: session id is known) other than the current page, you can:

```
select top 5 xpagename, COUNT(xpagename)as total 
FROM pagevisits 
WHERE pagevisits.xsession = 539447381
AND pagevisits.xpagename != 20
GROUP BY xpagename 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

where 539447381 is the current session id and 20 is the current page.

You can improve the performance of this if you can add a clustered index on xpagename and xsession:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [custom] ON [dbo].[pagevisits] 
(
    [xsession] ASC,
    [xpagename] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

PS: The question title said "Customer also viewed" and thus my answer. If the expected result is for returning the top 5 pages visited by other customers who viewed the current page, then the query given in the question is sufficient but add the clustered index for better performance (replaces table scans with clustered index seeks).

Comment: I believe the OP wanted a "People who viewed this also viewed" section - similar to Amazons "People who bought this also bought". So not a list that the current user viewed, but what other people who also viewed that product looked at.

Comment: The question title said "Customer also viewed" and thus my answer. If the expected result is for returning the top 5 pages visited by other customers who viewed the current page, then the query given in the question is perfect with the clustered index I suggested (to replace table scan with clustered index seeks).

Comment: Sorry perhaps I was vague in my wording. I want a way generating suggestions for other products. Since this is for a real estate website I can't use purchases!! The most viewed properties by other people who had viewed the same property seemed the best choice. I shall try the recommendations. Thanks for the prompt replies.